# Users complain they can't "click on anything" on my Pressflow site

Tags: 6

The users of [my site](http://www.transformationarts.org) complain they cannot click on anything on my site, which runs Pressflow.

If that makes any difference, I am using some Nginx Caching, and the server config from the Barracuda Aegir project.
I can't seem to figure this out, or reproduce it in another site.

Comment: To clarify, I have no idea what they are referring to, but 3 people have said it. I can go in FF/Chrome and click on any link, etc. to navigate, and it works fine. I looked through my error console, and there's a css issue that I can fix.but is that it?

Comment: I suggest ask to client be more specific/precise about the issue. I do not know if is related, but when I visited your site, the slider increase in an important level the load of CPU. Also, scroll down to the bottom seems not smooth.

Comment: Your users are talking about IE. No links work in IE8

Comment: I fixed the issue (which was general) 

I was using a microsoft css filter to scale the background image, it somehow made the whole page render incorrectly. removed filter, problem solved. can live without nice bg on IE for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue (which was general): I was using a Microsoft CSS filter to scale the background image. It somehow made the whole page render incorrectly. I removed filter, and the problem was solved. I can live without a nice background on IE, for now.

Comment: I've had a similar issue. I resolved the problem by having the IE filter on a separate, absolutely positioned div, behind the actual content.